# Github identify commits after a fork

Tags: git

I'm analyzing commits to a repo using the `git log` command. However, the repo was forked from a pre-existing repo, and I only want to look at commits that happened after the repo was forked.

How do I achieve this? I know that I can filter based on time (using `--since=<date>` and `--after=<date>` but I want to do this in an automated way without manually looking at the date of the fork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git merge-base original_repo/some_branch fork_repo/some_other_branch` will tell you the latest commit that the two branches have in common, and you can then use `git log` to look at the commits made after that commit.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `..` to specify a revision range would do this.

If your git history looks something like this, where

- `master` is the branch you forked from
- and `fork-branch` is the name of your fork

```
* 7b4c506 (HEAD -> fork-branch) more work
* e1faf6b work
* 5569418 (master) Upstream head
* e09c8ad some upsream commit
```

Then running `git log master..HEAD` will show all commits made since creating the fork.

Comment: this answer will also work in the branches actually forked : the diagram describes a situation where `fork-branch` is ahead of `master`, but it would also work if `master` had received extra commits on its side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the combined history of `origin/master` *and* `fork/master` on the same graph, you can use the three dots notation :

```
git log --graph origin/master...fork/master
```

---

Suppose your history looks like this :

```
* 20f7041 (origin/master) more work on origin
* c278977 work on origin
| * 68ca178 (fork/master) more work on fork
| * 2e47141 work on fork
|/  
* 0399c79 fork point
* 051f0c6 second commit
* 872afdf first commit
```

Then you would see :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph origin/master...fork/master
* 20f7041 (origin/master) more work on origin
* c278977 work on origin
* 68ca178 (fork/master) more work on fork
* 2e47141 work on fork
```

You can also add the `--boundary` option, to have `git log` display the common ancestor:

```
$ git log --boundary --oneline --graph origin/master...fork/master
* 20f7041 (origin/master) more work on origin
* c278977 work on origin
| * 68ca178 (fork/master) more work on fork
| * 2e47141 work on fork
|/  
o 0399c79 fork point
```